# Getting coordinates of current location iOS, Google Maps API

Tags: ios, google-maps

I've been struggling to change the camera's value in the Google Maps API. So that it displays the users position as soon as you open the app, using CoreLocation and passing those values into the camera.
There's some other tutorials online, but nothing that works for me.

If you could help it would be massively appreciated.

```
@implementation HMSBViewController{
    CLLocationManager *_locationManager;
}

- (NSString *)deviceLocation
{
    NSString *theLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", _locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, _locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    return theLocation;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation; // Setting the accuracy to the best possible


    if([_locationManager      respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)loadView{

    CLLocation *myLocation = mapView.myLocation;

    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position =   CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(myLocation.coordinate.latitude, myLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    marker.title = @"Current Location";
    marker.map = mapView;
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:_locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
                                                           longitude:_locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude
                                                             zoom:6];
    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

    self.view = mapView;
    NSLog(@"%f, %f", _locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, _locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);

    }
```

When the app runs the coordinates are always set to zero.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Google Maps API only get your current location after it's placed on the controller view. To solve this limitation you should create a notification that tells your controller when the current location is available.

On your viewWillApper add this observer:

```
[mapView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myLocation" options:0 context:nil];
```

Then add `-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` that is called everytime the `keyPath` value changes. On this method you can now get the current location and animate the map to it so it shows centered in there. At the end of the method you should deregister the observer since if it's not deregistered this method will be called every time the position changes.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"myLocation"]) {
        CLLocation *location = [object myLocation];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D target = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);

        [mapView animateToLocation:target];

        @try {
            [map removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myLocation"];
        } @catch(id exception){
            //do nothing, obviously it wasn't attached because an exception was thrown
        }
    }
}
```

The map can take a while to get the current location, but it's usually fast.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Makes a lot of sense, but I'm still not there.
I've added the observer and then the -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: method into the code, but it's still not working (new to iOS). In my load view do I need to pass in another value? Not _locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude/latitude anymore?

Comment: I think you don't need to pass nothing to your load view because when you initialize the view you don't have yet the current location. The flow is initialize your map, then add it to the view in your controller and then, because of the observer that was added on the viewWill appear, the -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: will be executed when the current location changes and there you can center the map on current location.

Comment: Did you grant permissions to the app to access location services as you do when using MapKit framework? That can be the problem if you still can't get the current location.