# User coordinates objective-C Google Maps API

Tags: ios, google-maps

I've cannot change the camera's value in the Google Maps API. So that it displays the users position as soon as you open the app, using CoreLocation and passing those values into the camera. I've had a look at some tutorials online, but I haven't managed to solve it yet.

I've tried to make a method that observes when the GPS coordinates have been found and then pass them to the camera. But it still shows 0,0.

```
@implementation HMSBViewController{

    CLLocationManager *_locationManager;
}

@synthesize mapView;

- (NSString *)deviceLocation
{
    NSString *theLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", _locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, _locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    return theLocation;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    mapView.delegate = self;
    //[mapView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myLocation" options:0 context:nil];

    //mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;       // Setting the accuracy to the best possible


    if([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

 }

- (void)viewWillAppear{

    [mapView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myLocation" options:0 context:nil];

}

- (void)loadView{

    CLLocation *myLocation = mapView.myLocation;

    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position =     CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(myLocation.coordinate.latitude,     myLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    marker.title = @"Current Location";
    marker.map = mapView;
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition  cameraWithLatitude:_locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
                                                          longitude:_locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude
                                                              zoom:1];
    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];


    self.view = mapView;
    NSLog(@"%f, %f", _locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, _locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);

}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"myLocation"]) {
        CLLocation *location = [object myLocation];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D target =    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude,    location.coordinate.longitude);

        [mapView animateToLocation:target];

        @try {
            [mapView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myLocation"];
        } @catch(id exception){
            ;
        }
     }
  }
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: 1. loadView will be called before viewDidLoad.  2. In loadView, you are accessing mapView.myLocation _before_ mapView has been created (later in the same method) and _before_ location manager has started (in viewDidLoad).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting coordinates of current location iOS, Google Maps API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212190/getting-coordinates-of-current-location-ios-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the locationManager delegate and then use the delegate method

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

to retrieve the location. Once you have the location, then call your map function to populate Google